# Why is calling gevent.idle()/sleep(0) multiple times making each call slower and slower?

Tags: python, performance, sleep, gevent

I have observed that calling `gevent.idle()` multiple times makes each successive call slower and slower. The same behaviour can be observed with `gevent.sleep(0)`.

With 100 calls:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup='import gevent', stmt='gevent.idle()', 
number=100)
0.0005408697757047776
```

With 100000 calls:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup='import gevent', stmt='gevent.idle()', 
number=100000)
0.5255624202554827
```

I thought `gevent.sleep`/`gevent.idle` would basically just check if there is something else to do or return immediately.

Why are the calls getting slower and slower?

Comment: It doesn't seem that each individual call is getting slower as you increased the number of calls by a factor of 10^3 and the time it took to occur increased by a factor of 10^3 which should make sense.

Comment: You are absolutely right I thought `timeit` returned the average time which it obviously does not. It returns the total time. Doh! =)